# Finding the solution to a matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, matrix-equations

I am reading the paper [Do dark matter axions form a condensate with long-range correlation?](https://link.aps.org/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.92.103513?casa_token=SIj_YkK_AHMAAAAA:19cSg7nWoEyr7RRAdhTbHBTBPhZCb-dSbFoOxHG-L9mbUXf7H2BhPM9NmnMRL34F6svKFYJu2PvU_cg).

Let
$$\psi = A + iB \tag{1}$$
Performing a Fourier Transform, you get $A_k$ and $B_k$.

It is found using a physical equation that $\psi$ satisfies that $A_k$ and $B_k$ obey
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\begin{bmatrix}
A_k\\
B_k
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{k^2}{2m} \\ -\frac{k^2}{2m}-\frac{\lambda n_0}{4m^2} & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_k \\ B_k\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$$

Defining
$$\kappa_k = \frac{k^2}{2m}+\frac{\lambda n_0}{4m^2} \tag{3}$$

The paper says that the solution to eqn(2) for $\kappa_k<0$ is

$$\psi_k = c_1(\gamma_k - i\kappa_k)e^{\gamma_kt} + c_2(\gamma_k + i\kappa_k)e^{-\gamma_kt} \tag{4}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary real constants and $\pm\gamma_k$ are the eigen vlaues of the above matrix,
$$\gamma_k = \frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}\sqrt{-\kappa_k}$$

My question is how can I get equation (4) from equation (2)?

Comment: Do you know how to solve [matrix ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) problems at all?

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link! It helped me solve the problem.